# PDFKit - bin/rails:6: warning: already initialized constant APP_PATH

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to ruby on rails. In order to use pdfKit I have followed these steps as mentioned in this link [How to use pdfkit with rails?](http://blog.andolasoft.com/2012/10/usage-of-pdfkit-with-rails-3-2-8-and-ruby-1-9-3.html#).

I have also re-installed the bundles. When I am trying to start my rails server I get the following error:

> bin/rails:6: warning: already initialized constant APP_PATH
>       Usage: rails COMMAND [ARGS]

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the following command:

```
rake rails:update:bin
```

If it says that you are missing some library; install that library, and again run this command.

After that simply do:

```
rails s
```

And your server will be up and running.

Comment: I have installed 'pdfkit' but its giving me error 'LoadError: cannot load such file -- pdfkit'.